# Optimization generate super long function definition

Tags: llvm

In my code, I generate the following function:

```
define i32 @gl.qi([500 x i32] %x, i32 %i) {
entry:
  %x. = alloca [500 x i32]
  %i. = alloca i32
  %0 = alloca [500 x i32]
  store [500 x i32] %x, [500 x i32]* %x.
  store i32 %i, i32* %i.
  %x.1 = load [500 x i32], [500 x i32]* %x.
  %i.2 = load i32, i32* %i.
  store [500 x i32] %x.1, [500 x i32]* %0
  %1 = icmp slt i32 %i.2, 500
  br i1 %1, label %in-bound, label %out-of-bound

out-of-bound:                                     ; preds = %entry
  call void @gen.panic(i8* getelementptr inbounds ([22 x i8], [22 x i8]* @pool.str.2, i32 0, i32 0))
  unreachable

in-bound:                                         ; preds = %entry
  %2 = getelementptr inbounds [500 x i32], [500 x i32]* %0, i32 0, i32 %i.2
  %idx = load i32, i32* %2
  ret i32 %idx
}
```

the high level functionality is to use `%i` to index `%x`, and if `%i` is out of bound, a panic function is called instead.

consider the store line:

```
  store [500 x i32] %x, [500 x i32]* %x.
```

once I pass this function to `opt -O1 -S --verify --verify-each`, it generates code like this:

```
define i32 @gl.qi([500 x i32] %x, i32 %i) local_unnamed_addr {
entry:
  %0 = alloca [500 x i32], align 4
  %x.fca.0.extract = extractvalue [500 x i32] %x, 0
  %x.fca.1.extract = extractvalue [500 x i32] %x, 1
  %x.fca.2.extract = extractvalue [500 x i32] %x, 2
  %x.fca.3.extract = extractvalue [500 x i32] %x, 3
  %x.fca.4.extract = extractvalue [500 x i32] %x, 4
  %x.fca.5.extract = extractvalue [500 x i32] %x, 5
```

until 500. I put the number to 50000 and it won't stop.

This is puzzling. I am not sure why must a `store` command be expanded to a sequence of `etractvalue`s then `store`s? Is there a way to turn off this particular optimization without turning off the whole optimization?

Or am I looking at the wrong way to do this simple task?

Answer (score 0):

To store `%x` in `%x` you need to first load the values from `%x` (function call arguments) before storing them back in `%x` (local variable). That's what the `extractvalue` and subsequent `store` is for. Same thing for `%i`. So it's not an optimization. It's just the way a variable `a` gets assigned to another variable `b`